# Installing curb on ruby1.8.6

Tags: ruby, windows, curl, curb

I cannot install curb on Windows 7 x64 with ruby1.8.6 p111:

```
ruby extconf.rb install curb-0.8.1.gem -- --with-curl-dir=C:\curl-7.26.0
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in curl.lib... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby186/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:18:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include options to extconf.
```

For clarification, `C:\curl-7.26.0` is a [libcurl v7.26.0](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.26.0/dist-w32/curl-7.26.0-devel-mingw32.zip) with `lib/bin/include` folders.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same answer I provided here applies to your issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484346/117298

But I highly recommend you upgrade at least to Ruby 1.8.7, considering 1.8.6 is no longer maintained and 1.8.7 End-Of-Life has been announced already.