# Gem installation error: You have to install development tools first (Windows)

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra

**this question is for Windows**

I tried installing the gem '[sinatra-websocket](https://github.com/simulacre/sinatra-websocket)', but when I ran `gem install sinatra-websocket`, I got this error...

`ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`

... along with ...

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
    --with-thin_parser-dir
    --without-thin_parser-dir
    --with-thin_parser-include
    --without-thin_parser-include=${thin_parser-dir}/include
    --with-thin_parser-lib
    --without-thin_parser-lib=${thin_parser-dir}/lib
    --with-clib
    --without-clib
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Here's what the `mkmf` file in `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\thin-1.6.3\ext\thin_parser` looks like:

```
"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -DFD_SETSIZE=2048  -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L.   -march=i486   -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

I'm using Windows 7.

Why am I getting the error? There's a line stating "could not create Makefile...", but is that relevant?

Comment: The mkmf.log file can be found under the gem's installation directory.

Comment: @siaw23 I've added the contents of the file

Comment: Have you got a C compiler installed?

Comment: @iain How do I check that? And where can I find an installation?

Comment: The one I've used in the past is [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). From [this](http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_Windows_using_MinGW#Testing_MinGW.2FMSYS_installation) you can try `make -v` and
`gcc -v` to check. You might try installing [the Ruby dev kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)

Comment: Check this answer out, it's detailed and better than any advice I could give. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11484346/335847

Comment: if you are getting this on a Mac when running bundle install--- for example, for puma  5.6.2, I have made a separate SO post because this one is specific to Windows (as well there is no XCode on windows so all these XCode answers are very confusing) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383295/installing-puma-5-6-2-with-native-extensions-gemextbuilderror-error-failed

Answer (score 212):

**Also for Mac:**

if you do not already have xcode dev tools installed on your system (perhaps you recently upgraded your OS or Xcode), run `xcode-select --install`

otherwise, a more invasive fix is to set the active directory using the `--switch` flag

`sudo xcode-select --switch /`

from the xcode-select manual:

```
  -s <path>, --switch <path>
          Sets the active developer directory to the given path, for example
          /Applications/Xcode-beta.app. This command must be run with
          superuser permissions (see sudo(8)), and will affect all users on
          the system. To set the path without superuser permissions or only
          for the current shell session, use the DEVELOPER_DIR environment
          variable instead (see ENVIRONMENT).
```

If you already have Xcode installed, you may have a different problem, in which case, see this post [Installing puma 5.6.2 with native extensions Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71383295/installing-puma-5-6-2-with-native-extensions-gemextbuilderror-error-failed)

Comment: I already had command line tools installed, and this worked for me also. Thanks!

Comment: Did not help me

Comment: Helped me with failing `gem install psych -v '3.0.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

Comment: `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/'` i got this error

Comment: I ran into this error when doing `sudo gem install cocoapods`, it fixed my issue there. Can anyone explain what it does to fix the error?

Comment: Wow this worked for me. Thank you! (installing a Cococpods plugin - https://github.com/joncardasis/cocoapods-user-defined-build-types). Also curious why this fixes the issue!

Comment: This worked for me as well. What are we doing here.

Comment: This answer needs more of an explanation. The fact that it A) requires sudo, B) I don't know what xcode is, and C) looks to operate on the root folder are three huge red flags for a novice.

Comment: This work well in my case.

Comment: I downgraded from Xcode 13.2 to 13.1 - after that the problem occurred (Something was messed up with the Xcode command line tools). This fixed my problem.  After that i had to select the Command Line in Tools in Xcode -> Preferences ->  Locations -> Command Line Tools.

Comment: At first, I didn't think this solution will help. But it did.

Answer (score 70):

I was having this issue on MacOS Mojave(10.14.1). Installing latest ruby via Homebrew and setting some env variables solved it for me:

(copied from `brew info ruby` instructions)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Comment: If you installed ruby via brew, you can get those env variables with `brew info ruby`

Comment: This answer fixed my issue when trying to use the Sass compiler after the recent OSX update

Comment: This worked for a failing `inspec` installation

Comment: works for Catalina 10.15.7, many thanks.

Comment: Worked for Big Sur 11.6.5, thanks.

Comment: This still seems to be valid on macOS 12.6. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, works on an M1 os 12.6.x (I already had xcode tools installed for work)

Answer (score 67):

***For a Mac:***

Have you run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

To install the Xcode Developer tools?

Comment: I don't think the "development tools" being referenced in the error has anything to do with xcode, especially considering this is on Windows.

Comment: I moved to a new machine and forgot about xcode command line tools as a separate install to XCode. This helped thanks. I was struggling with `gem install puma`

Comment: The original question definitely stated Windows, but regardless - this helped me on a Mac!

Comment: Just what I was missing on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: 'xcode-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You might need to set the Command Line Tools in Xcode.
1. Open Xcode
2. Navigate to Xcode > Preferences > Locations 
3. Set the Command Line Tools to the version of Xcode you have installed

Comment: (On Mac OSx Mojave) After running `xcode-select --install`, close and re-open the terminal. Then, run `sudo xcodebuild -license`, follow the instructions and finally accept the license agreement. In my experiment, this was the solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Hilariously, this answer is STILL the top search result, even for OSX. It's _accidentally_ the best answer.

Answer (score 56):

I ran into this same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.  The fix on Ubuntu was to install the `ubuntu-dev-tools` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools
```

Comment: thank you, works for me! on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you.  I struggled with this for a while on 20.04 also

Comment: I'm working on docker and host machine is ubuntu as container is. This worked very well for me, thank you mate.

Comment: I searched for a lot of different solutions, this fixed it as make was missing.

Answer (score 27):

edit: rubyinstaller now provides installs with the devkit included. These are labelled on the download page.

Sounds like you're missing the devtools for ruby.

You can get them here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ just scroll down to "Development Kit".

Download and extract that to anywhere you want. Open up the folder in command prompt and run `ruby dk.rb init`. This will create a config file detailing your ruby installations. Check this config file before continuing to confirm the paths to your ruby installation are correct.

Now run `ruby dk.rb install`. This will install the development kit.

Restart command prompt, and try to install the gem again.

Answer (score 25):

Tried all previous answers but none worked.

Did this instead:

```sh
brew install cocoapods
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. I struggled with `The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.` for some time.

Comment: I'm a Mac user and have Xcode running. This works for me.

Comment: This installed ruby for me, and also libyaml. Could be one of those two were the original culprit. (I had ruby 2.x.x, it installed ruby 3.1.2)

Answer (score 18):

If you're on Mac and recently upgraded your Xcode tools, run the following commands:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: I was able to execute your steps without error on Mojave, but they didn't help me with the error "You have to install development tools first".

Answer (score 18):

My issue was that I updated to macOS Big Sur, and somehow, the command line tools were outdated.

I know this because, when I tried to run `brew install rbenv`, I received this error:

```
Error: Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 11.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your Command Line Tools (CLT) or delete it if no updates are available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
```

So I ran

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and after it finished, the gem installed successfully.

Comment: This worked just fine without the removal of the CommandLineTools directory   Thanks!

Comment: Thank you this helped me install cocoa pods on m1 Mac mini.

Answer (score 8):

If you're on Mac OS 10.14 (Mojave) try

```
cd  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/;
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Credit to Roy Huang
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55732339/1598551

Comment: I was able to execute your steps without error on Mojave, but they didn't help me with the error "You have to install development tools first".

Answer (score 7):

This solution saved me:

1. Install `homebrew` via terminal.
2. After homebrew is successfully installed, type in the terminal

   '`$ brew install cocoapods`'

And Finally Done!

update: You can install `homebrew` by this command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

[from here](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: Plz elaborate on how to install homebrew via terminal! Step by step, plz.

Comment: Anyway, it did it!  (I used the command: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` from: https://brew.sh/ . Feel free to put that in your answer!)

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Thanks, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution for mac OSX:

In the Terminal App:

Step 1: Make sure you have installed the Xcode developer tool by the following script:

`xcode-select --install`

Step 2: Upgrade your ruby by the script:

`brew install ruby`

Step 3: Try again.

Comment: I tryed anything on the earch, more that two days, I am in MacOS 10.15.7 catalina, xcode 12.3, trying to develop nativescript apps, and finallay this solution worked for me and cocoapods installed successfully. thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

This means you don't have compiler tools installed. For mac `xcode-select --install` installs them. For linux or other systems you can use package managers, for example `apt install cmake` should install the necessary build tools for systems having apt package manager.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the real problem is when one upgrades from a major version of macOS to another and installs a newer Xcode.

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
ls -l SDKs/
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   14 Feb  4 21:41 MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX11.1.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 Feb  4 21:43 MacOSX10.15.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Feb  4 21:43 MacOSX11.1.sdk
```

After going to Apple's developer site and downloading the CLI tools by hand, this is what the folder contains:

```
$> ls -l SDKs/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   14 May  4 18:10 MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX11.3.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  256 May  4 18:10 MacOSX10.15.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Feb  4 21:43 MacOSX11.1.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  224 Mar 16 10:03 MacOSX11.3.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   14 May  4 18:09 MacOSX11.sdk -> MacOSX11.3.sdk
```

You might still need to reset your Xcode with:

```
$> sudo xcode-select --reset
$> sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Verify with:

```
$> sudo xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Lastly, if you still see errors compiling something, you will need to pay close attention to what the compiler error is and address it. For example, in my case, it was simply that in macOS Big Sur clang needs special arguments to add declarations (struct). It was fixed with:

```
export CFLAGS="-fdeclspec $CFLAGS"
```

This was the error if you're curious (or anybody looking for an answer for Ruby 3.0.x online):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.1/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:285:1: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec attributes
```

Answer (score 2):

I had recently upgraded to MAC OS big sur, and started getting the error when running gem install...

Solution is to remove the CLT completely and run the installation again.

Optional :

> brew upgrade

Run :

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

> sudo xcode-select --install

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) -- **WSL**

There are some dependencies to solve before, try with following sequence of commands:

```sh
# if ERROR: 'Gem installation error: You have to install development tools first'
# BEFORE installing the dev-tools, install dependencies:
# if ERROR: 'GCC fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory'
$ sudo apt-get install libc6
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150282/5078874
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

# Now, go for the development tools
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442072/5078874
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools

# Finally, try again
$ bundle update --bundler
# ... enjoy :)
```

References:

- [@Doug's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3520607/doug-couvillion) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442072/5078874) PLUS references below
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150282/5078874

Answer (score 2):

This is works for my Mac.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of Xcode installed, make sure you select the command line tools from the most recent one, otherwise gem will not be able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

On **macOS Catalina**; After running `$ brew install coreutils` [(credit)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241778/5736713) –– I followed an older [article](https://evanhoffman.com/2014/07/29/you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-osx-mavericks-ruby-chef-and-nokogiri/) by Evan Hoffman, installing chef ( *which embeds latest stable release of Ruby* )

`$ curl -L https://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash`

Then I can install any gems needed, with all the requisite development tools now installed;

`$ sudo gem install -V <gem>`

Your mileage may vary on Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, for me worked by doing a:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

I had xcode-select previously installed, but it was not working anyway. Doing a --reset fixed this for me.