# gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11' failed due to make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

> Ruby version: 2.2.5
>
> Mac OSX: 10.11.5
>
> Gem version: 2.4.8
>
> Bundler version: 1.12.5

When I run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'`, I got the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/hwpeng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160707-31800-1ejznjc.rb extconf.rb

====ignored multiple lines====

make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.nokogiri.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I noticed the error message said: `make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory`.

I searched this in google and found a similar post but for cocopods: https://coderwall.com/p/ehijxg/fixing-error-installing-cocoapods-on-macos

The following commands solved my problem. If you have a different error message, please refer to http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

### Homebrew

```
brew install coreutils
gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'
```

### MacPorts

```
sudo port install coreutils
gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.11'
```

Comment: Installing coreutils did the trick for me.
Had some error with json 1.8.3 and ruby 2.2.5.

Comment: Why do gem authors assume global packages are installed and don't check for them or include them in install instructions?

Comment: I had an issue installing `rugged` and `coreutils` was the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem last time and you can try this code:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.11 -- --use-system-libraries
```

I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not directly linked with the nokogiri. It is more around the missing libraries in the system. I am using Mac M1 machine and moving data/libraries from Intel to M1 is a pain. So for me after spending hours I fixed the issue. Steps which I followed to fix library issues are:

- Uninstall and install Homebrew
- Update the proper `PATH` in .zshrc or .bachrc file
- install the coreutils `brew install coreutils`
- close the terminal and then run the `bundle install`

Credit for coreutils help: http://thoughtsthatleakedout.blogspot.com/2011/10/problem-with-gmkdir-when-updating-gems.html

Comment: What will happen to all my installed apps when I uninstall homebrew?