# How to resolve gem install pg error on macOS

Tags: ruby, postgresql, macos

I am trying to write a ruby program to connect to PostgreSQL database. Since, I will be using the `pg` and `pg_query` ruby extension, I am trying to install them by running:

`gem install pg`

or

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config` and am getting the following error:

```
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

.

.
.
.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from extconf.rb:40:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me get this issue resolved?

FYI - I am new to macOS and Ruby.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gem installation error: You have to install development tools first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768420/895789)

Comment: Thank you guys. I actually had to install a new version of ruby (3.0) on my macBook and everything started working after that :-)