# `bundle update --ruby` leads to puma installation crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

in trying to bump from Ruby 3.1.0 to 3.1.1, I'm getting this hiccup:

```
% bundle update --ruby       
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.6
Using racc 1.6.0
Using crass 1.0.6
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using digest 3.1.0
Using io-wait 0.2.1
Using timeout 0.2.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using strscan 3.0.1
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using msgpack 1.4.5
Using bundler 2.3.7
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using regexp_parser 2.2.1
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using rack 2.2.3
Using zeitwerk 2.5.4
Using builder 3.2.4
Using docile 1.4.0
Using ffaker 2.20.0
Using uniform_notifier 1.14.2
Using kaminari-core 1.2.2
Using childprocess 4.1.0
Using pg 1.3.3
Using rspec-support 3.11.0
Using redis 4.6.0
Using simplecov-html 0.12.3
Using simplecov_json_formatter 0.1.4
Using vcr 6.0.0
Using nokogiri 1.13.3 (arm64-darwin)
Using i18n 1.10.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.4
Using net-protocol 0.1.2
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using dotenv 2.7.6
Using thor 1.2.1
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using sprockets 4.0.2
Using diff-lcs 1.5.0
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using net-imap 0.2.3
Using matrix 0.4.2
Using net-pop 0.1.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using rspec-core 3.11.0
Using simplecov 0.21.2
Using rspec-expectations 3.11.0
Using bootsnap 1.10.3
Using net-smtp 0.3.1
Using selenium-webdriver 4.1.0
Using activesupport 7.0.2.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using webdrivers 5.0.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using bullet 7.0.1
Using capybara 3.36.0
Using loofah 2.14.0
Using globalid 1.0.0
Using activemodel 7.0.2.2
Using rspec-mocks 3.11.0
Using activejob 7.0.2.2
Using factory_bot 6.2.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Fetching puma 5.6.1
Using rspec 3.11.0
Using actionview 7.0.2.2
Using activerecord 7.0.2.2
Using jbuilder 2.11.5
Using actionpack 7.0.2.2
Using kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
Using rspec-wait 0.0.9
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
Using actioncable 7.0.2.2
Using kaminari 1.2.2
Using actionmailer 7.0.2.2
Using railties 7.0.2.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Using activestorage 7.0.2.2
Using stimulus-rails 1.0.4
Using cssbundling-rails 1.1.0
Using dotenv-rails 2.7.6
Using actionmailbox 7.0.2.2
Using jsbundling-rails 1.0.2
Using rspec-rails 5.1.0
Using turbo-rails 1.0.1
Using web-console 4.2.0
Using factory_bot_rails 6.2.0
Using actiontext 7.0.2.2
Using rails 7.0.2.2
Using hot-glue 0.4.9.2
Installing puma 5.6.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/puma-5.6.1/ext/puma_http11
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
./siteconf20220301-55707-uxz2j9.rb extconf.rb --with-cflags\=-Wno-error\=implicit-function-declaration
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-puma_http11-dir
    --without-puma_http11-dir
    --with-puma_http11-include
    --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
    --with-puma_http11-lib
    --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-dir
    --without-openssl-dir
    --with-openssl-include
    --without-openssl-include=${openssl-dir}/include
    --with-openssl-lib
    --without-openssl-lib=${openssl-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-crypto-dir
    --without-crypto-dir
    --with-crypto-include
    --without-crypto-include=${crypto-dir}/include
    --with-crypto-lib
    --without-crypto-lib=${crypto-dir}/lib
    --with-cryptolib
    --without-cryptolib
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:498:in `try_do': The compiler failed to
generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:591:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:609:in `try_link'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:830:in `try_func'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1065:in `block in have_library'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1007:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:362:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `open'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:358:in `postpone'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1006:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1060:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `find'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/puma-5.6.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/gems/puma-5.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.1/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/puma-5.6.1/gem_make.out

  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in `run'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in
build'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in `build'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `build_extension'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `block in
build_extensions'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `each'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in `build_extensions'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in
`build_extensions'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
/Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'

An error occurred while installing puma (5.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  puma
%
```

*Mac OS Monteray 12.2 *

please note this is similar to the already-asked question at [Gem installation error: You have to install development tools first (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768420/gem-installation-error-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-windows) however that question is intended for Windows and has what appear to be answers for Xcode.

I've already tried the xcode install this does not seem to work .

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this bug keeps coming back to me. the standard fix is:

`xcode-select --install`

This also happens on puma 5.6.1 it will "hiccup." Remove Puma 5.6.1 from Gemfile.lock file and `bundle install` and it should puck up 5.6.2

if this doesn't work try `brew install gcc`

today however neither one fixed it, and I had to run this which then seems to have fixed the problem.

`gem install puma -v '5.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

I think somehow the global-installed puma gets stuck although I didn't thoroughly identify this.