# Jekyll install failed with "extconf failed, exit code 1" on Mac OS

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll

I followed the instructions at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/ and ultimately ran into this error. Here are some other things I ran into along the way.

```
xcode-select --install
```

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)
```

> Just went to a new line in the terminal with no message. seemed successful.

```
Install Homebrew
```

> (was already installed)

```
brew install ruby
```

> fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
> Warning: No available formula with the name "ruby".
> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
> These similarly named formulae were found:
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-libyaml
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ncurses
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-readline
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby
> homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-zlib
> To install one of them, run (for example):
> brew install homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-libyaml
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
> Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
> Error: No formulae found in taps.

```
# If you're using Zsh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

> Just went to a new line in the terminal with no message. seemed successful.

Quit and relaunched Terminal.

```
which ruby
```

> /usr/bin/ruby

```
ruby -v
```

> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]

```
gem install --user-install bundler jekyll
```

> WARNING:  You don't have /Users/my-username/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin in your PATH,
> gem executables will not run. Successfully installed bundler-2.3.9
> Parsing documentation for bundler-2.3.9
> Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
> /Users/my-username/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0
> -r ./siteconf20220321-36161-h5kjlp.rb extconf.rb checking for -lcrypto... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.
> Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.

(some info about configuration omitted)

> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in
> > `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in` block in try_link0'  from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in
> > `mktmpdir'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in` try_link0'   from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in
> > `try_link'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:789:in` try_func'    from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1016:in
> > `block in have_library'   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'   from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> > `block (2 levels) in postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
> > `block in postpone'   from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'    from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in
> > `postpone'    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'    from
> > /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1011:in
> > `have_library'    from extconf.rb:8:in` block in check_libs'  from
> > extconf.rb:8:in `all?'    from extconf.rb:8:in` check_libs'   from
> > extconf.rb:95:in `'
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
> which can be found here:

(file path omitted)

[gem_make.out file linked here](https://pastebin.com/EzbdgeME)

Mac OS 11.6.3

Comment: The key is `You have to install development tools first`. Have you tried  [each one of the macos-related answers here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27768420/895789)